# Got 415 error "Unsupported Media Type" when use wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I tried to send a POST request from WordPress to an external API (assign a tag to an user in a CRM system). When I used cURL, everything was OK. Here is the cURL code:

```php
function my_function () {

$body = array ( 'tags' => array ( array (
                        'email' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
                        'tag' => 'Customer5'
                        ))
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "$api_url",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body, true),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "User-Agent: Your App Name (www.yourapp.com)",
    "Authorization: Basic xxxxxx"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_function');
```

But then I switched to use `wp_remote_post`, I got a "415 - Unsupported Media Type" response.

```php
$body = array ( 'tags' => array (
                            array(
                                'email' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
                                'tag' => 'Customer5'
                            ))
);

$headers = array (
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'User-Agent' => 'Your App Name (www.yourapp.com)',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic xxxxxx',
);

$request = wp_remote_post('$api_url', $arg );

$arg = array (
    'header' => $headers,
    'body' => json_encode($body, true),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'sslverify' => false,
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($request);
echo '</pre>';
```

I tried a lot of modifications (changed associative array format to key:value pair, add `AddType` to `htaccess` file...), but nothing worked. Please help, I'm stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/support/415-unsupported-media-type):

> A `415 Unsupported Media Type` error occurs when the origin server
> **refuses a particular request** since the resource is in a format that is not supported by the server for the [HTTP
> method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)
> used. This unsupported format type issue can be caused by what is
> defined in the resource's `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding`
> headers.

And in your case, the error happened most likely because your remote request sent the wrong `Content-Type` header — which defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when the HTTP method is POST.

And yes, you did include the right `Content-Type` value in your `$headers` array. But unfortunately in your `$arg` array which you passed to `wp_remote_post()`, you used the *wrong array key* — `header`, which should actually be `headers` (note the "s").

So use `headers` and not `header`, just as you can see below:

```php
$api_url = 'your API URL';

$body = array(
    'tags' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
            'tag'   => 'Customer5',
        ),
    ),
);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
    'User-Agent'    => 'Your App Name (www.yourapp.com)',
    'Authorization' => 'Basic xxxxxx',
);

$arg = array(
    'headers'   => $headers, // good
//  'header'    => $headers, // bad; i.e. wrong array key ('header')
    'body'      => json_encode( $body ),
    // 'method' can be omitted since you're using wp_remote_post()
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'sslverify' => false,
);

$request = wp_remote_post( $api_url, $arg );
// ..if the response still isn't good, what's the output of this:
var_dump( $request );
```